# JUnit test fails in Ant with `<junit>` task but passes with `<exec>`?

Tags: java, ant, build, junit, junit4

I am automating my JUnit tests into my Ant build. However, my simple test only passes when run from the IDE and commandline but fails with Ant's `<junit>` task. When I run it from the commandline (I am technically using the Ant `<exec>` task) the result is:

```
clean:

compile_tests:
    [javac] Compiling 2 source files to C:\MY_TEMP

junit_exec:
     [exec] JUnit version 4.10
     [exec] .
     [exec] Time: 0.004
     [exec]
     [exec] OK (1 test)
     [exec]

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
```

but when I use the `<junit>` task:

```
Buildfile: C:\MY_TEMP\build.xml

clean:

compile_tests:
    [javac] Compiling 2 source files to C:\MY_TEMP

junit_ant:
     [echo] junit_ant started
    [junit] Test SimpleTest FAILED

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

The contents of `MY_TEMP` are `junit-4.10.jar`, `SimpleTest.java`, and `build.xml`.

I have copied `junit-4.10.jar` to the `%ANT_HOME%\lib` folder as suggest by the [Ant junit task documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html). It already had both `ant-junit.jar` and `ant-junit4.jar`.

My version of Java is 1.6.0_26.

My test is:

```
// YES, this is the default package
import org.junit.*;

public class SimpleTest {

    @Test
    public void mySimpleTest(){
        Assert.assertEquals(  2,  1 + 1  );
    }

}
```

And my Ant file (build.xml ), is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="regression_tests" basedir=".">

    <target name="clean">
        <delete>
            <fileset dir="." includes="*.class" />
        </delete>
    </target>

    <target name="compile_tests" depends="clean">
            <javac srcdir="." destdir="." source="1.6" target="1.6" includeantruntime="false" >
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="./junit-4.10.jar" />
            </classpath>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="junit_ant" depends="compile_tests" >
        <echo message="junit_ant started" />

        <junit>
            <test name="SimpleTest" />
        </junit>
    </target>

    <target name="junit_exec" depends="compile_tests">
        <exec executable="java" dir="." >
            <arg value="-classpath" />
            <arg value=".;junit-4.10.jar" />
            <arg value="org.junit.runner.JUnitCore" />
            <arg value="SimpleTest" />
        </exec>
    </target>

</project>
```

Comment: What's the test failure?

Comment: How would I find that out? Even with the `-v` option given to Ant it doesn't print anything regarding the failure. Judging from the test itself which cannot fail I figure I must be missing something configuration-wise.

Comment: Look in the test report?

Comment: Where would one find that? I assume that it is an option that would need to be enabled? I tried both `enableTestListenerEvents="true"` and `logfailedtests="yes"`. I'm used to Maven's surefire reports.

Comment: Nevermind, found how to make reports from here: http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/faq/faq.htm#running_6

Comment: You'd need to pass it in to your `junit_exec` target, but ew--there's a [junit task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) that wraps all this up for you. *Edit* Ah, yep, you beat me to it :)

Comment: It was `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SimpleTest` so I added `<classpath location="." />` to the `<junit>` tag. If you want to post that as an answer I'd be happy to accept it! :) If anything the real problem seems to be that I wasn't seeing the failure, since it seemed pretty obvious once I did.

Comment: It's always obvious once you see it ;) But yeah, when it works one way and not the other, it's almost *always* classpath-related :/ Ah, Java :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a test passes one way, and fails another, it's likely something classpath-related, like it can't find a test class, a class under test, or a library.

The test output should help clarify if this is what the issue is.

Answer (score 2):

Specifically I editted my `junit_ant` task to:

```
        <junit>
            <classpath location="." />

            <test name="SimpleTest" />
            <formatter type="xml" />
        </junit>

        <junitreport todir=".">
            <fileset dir=".">
                <include name="TEST-*.xml" />
            </fileset>
            <report todir="." />
        </junitreport>
```

Which then showed me that the failure was `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SimpleTest` so I just added `<classpath location="." />` to the `<junit>` task and then it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Add this line for more info:

```
<formatter type="brief" usefile="false"/>
```